# Null String from nowhere.

Tags: java, android, list

I have a basic `ArrayList<Car>` and I want to use it to make a `String[]`. Pretty easy, but I get a null in my String from nowhere, and I do not understand the problem. 

Here is my function.

```
private String[] makeListOfCars(){
        Log.d("1st Car brand ", user.getCars().get(0).getBrand());
        Log.d("2nd Car brand ", user.getCars().get(1).getBrand());
        String result[] = new String[user.getCars().size()]; // Size > 0 because the user have at least one car here
        for(int i = 0 ; i < user.getCars().size() ; i++){
            result[i] += user.getCars().get(i).getBrand() + " " + user.getCars().get(i).getModel();
            Log.d("Result ", result[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And here is the output I get:

> 03-04 13:49:32.470  27216-27216/com.example.bla.app D/1st Car brand﹕
>   Bmw 
> 03-04 13:49:32.470  27216-27216/com.example.bla.app D/2nd Car
>   brand﹕ Volvo 
> 03-04 13:49:32.470  27216-27216/com.example.bla.app
>   D/Result﹕ nullBmw 335i 
> 03-04 13:49:32.470 
>   27216-27216/com.example.bla.app D/Result﹕ nullVolvo V40

Can someone explain me from where this null come from?

Comment: try:             result[i] = user.getCars().get(i).getBrand() + " " + user.getCars().get(i).getModel(); (instead of +=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
result[i] += user.getCars().get(i).getBrand() + " " + user.getCars().get(i).getModel();
```

to

```
result[i] = user.getCars().get(i).getBrand() + " " + user.getCars().get(i).getModel();
```

The "null" is appended because the initial value of `result[i]` is null, and when you concatenate a `null` value to a String, the `null` becomes the `"null"` String.

Comment: So freaking dumb ... Thank you! Too much time in front my PC I guess :) Nice answer btw.